# How works sessionmaker with pool?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

I'm new in sqlalchemy orm and can't fully understand how sessionmaker works with engine that was made with a connection pool

```
self._engine: AsyncEngine = create_async_engine(db_url,
                                                echo=debug_mode,
                                                pool_size=pool_size,
                                                max_overflow=3)
self._session_factory = sessionmaker(self._engine,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     expire_on_commit=False,
                                     class_=AsyncSession)
```

I know that ORM establishes connection directly at the time of adding an object. So if I'm using *pool_size=3* and making 3 big queries with long processing time in different endpoints using

```
async with self._session_factory.begin() as session:
    ......
```

will orm establish 3 db connections, or still use one??

The point is how can I use sqlalchemy with classic asyncpg pool manager benefits?